# FMX TEdit duplicating first input when auto-correct is enabled

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I'm currently working in an Android Application using Delphi 10 Seattle.
I own an Galaxy Tab E (SM-T560) and an Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini to test this application and when the "smart text" option of samsung's keyboard is enabled, the first input to a TEdit gets duplicated, setting the smart text off fixes the issue, I was able to find this "fix" in this embarcadero forum thread: [More strange behaviour, keyboard this time](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=213598).

As this option is enabled by default on samsung devices, I'm not going to keep ask our clients to disable this option, I want to fix this problem with TEdit, the question is: HOW?

So far, that thread is the only place I was able to find someone talking about this and they haven't found an straight fix to this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `TEdit` `KeyboardType` property to `Alphabet`

Comment: I'm going to accept ur reply as correct answer because it makes sense, but it's been a while since it happened... my guess was that embarcadero fixed it...